# GraphQL: wrap external api no results

Tags: javascript, api, graphql

Im trying to wrap an external api with a grahql server.
If i call the following endpoint on the external api: `https://api.goingelectric.de/chargepoints/?key=secret&lat=49.5543&lng=11.0257&radius=5&ge_id=900`

im recieving a correct result:

```
{
"status": "ok",
"chargelocations": [
    {
        "ge_id": 900,
        "name": "Rathausplatz",
        "address": {
            "city": "Erlangen",
            "country": "Deutschland",
            "postcode": "91052",
            "street": "Schuhstraße 44"
        },
        "coordinates": {
            "lat": 49.591301,
            "lng": 11.0087
        },
        "chargepoints": [
            {
                "count": 2,
                "power": 22,
                "type": "Typ2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

But if try to call this endpoint with graphql im recieving always `null`
So here is my schema.js:

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/FlonTaut/bc1bf5f653ff737b7db78aaabc0ce52a.js"></script>
```

Its the exact same call to the endpoint but im recieving no answer.
Do i need to rename my `json.station` to `json.chargepoints` or is the answer `status: ok` doing some trouble and i need to ignore it somehow?

I can add the way i run the query later but its just

```
station(lat:...,lng:...) {
 name
 address {
   city
   street
}
```

for example with the same coordinates
if i missed any information needed please let me know

thanks already

EDIT: Now i tryed some more and have a different problem now.
Thats my current `StationType` so the hole thing:

```
const StationType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: "Station",
description: "...",

fields: {
    name : { 
        type: GraphQLString,
        description: "Name of the Station",
        resolve: (parent, args, context) => {
            return parent.name;
        }
    },
    address: {
        type: new GraphQLObjectType(AdressType)
    },
    coordinates: {
        type: new GraphQLObjectType(CoordType)
    }

}

})
```

And this is my `CoordType` containing the coordinates:
`const CoordType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Coodinates",
    description: "Object containing the Latitude and Longitude of a Chargepoint",

```
fields: () => ({
    lat: { 
        type: GraphQLString, 
        description: "Latitude Coordinates of the Chargepoint",
        resolve: (parent, args, context) => {
            return parent.coordinates.lat;
        }
    },
    lng: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        description: "Longtitude Coordinates of the Chargepoint",
        resolve: (parent, args, context) => {
            return parent.coordinates.lng;
        }
    }
})
})
```

But im know recieving the following error when opening GraphiQL:
`Type Coodinates must define one or more fields."` And the same for AdressType. So wheres the Problem here? CoordType is defining exactly two fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return in your resolve. Right now you just make the network call and then no nothing with the result.

You have:

```
resolve: (root, args) => {
  getStationsByURL(`lat=${args.lat}&lng=${args.lng}&radius=5`)
}
```

You need:

```
resolve: (root, args) => {
  return <network call + any data access inside of it that's needed>
}
```

The default return value in Javascript is `undefined`, and graphql will convert `undefined` returned by resolvers to `null`.

UPDATE: based on the conversation in the comments below:

Suppose the object returned from your JSON response looks like:

```
{
  data: {
    bar: 1337,
    foo: 'Hi',
  }
}
```

Then your graphql type definition might look like:

```
const MyType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'MyType',
  fields: {
    bar: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
      resolve: (parent, args, context) => {
        return parent.data.bar;
      },
    },
    foo: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (parent, args, context) => {
        return parent.data.foo;
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Do note that GraphQL provides a default resolver. So for example, if the data returned from your API call looks like:

```
{
  bar: 1337,
  foo: 'Hi',
}
```

Then you wouldn't need to provide any resolvers. The default resolver uses the name of the field and tries to find that same name in the parent object.

Comment: So isnt it enough to return the fetch inside the `getStationsByURL`? Could you please provide an example i dont exactly understand what you mean

Comment: You need to return some value from the resolver. Returning inside of `getStationsByURL` makes the value accessible in the resolver, but you then need to actually `return getStationsByURL()` in the resolver, or, if needed, `return getStationsByURL.then(data => data.myValue)`

Comment: Now i got that working and am sure that the result is correctly returned to the resolver. But i still have `null` in "name" and "address" field, they are named the same in my graphql and the json i recieve

Comment: Do i probably need to add a resolver to every GraphQLObject? The json is returned but GraphQL still says `null` to i need to resolve it from need to do something like this (pseudo) `json => GraphQLString` ?

Comment: There is no default type in graphql that support returning JSON from, you so you need to pull the value of each field out of the JSON response and return the correct value for the field. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: thank you, tried it out but im know recieving a completely different error message, could you help me with this too?

Comment: I got it working now with the parent thing, figured out how i can access the data and fixed the error i told before by not using `new GraphQLObjectType(AddressType)`